# OpenZeppelin AccessControl state shared between contracts rather that inheriting

Tags: solidity, contract-development, openzeppelin-contracts

I have contracts `Marketplace` and `Escrow`, and I want to share `AccessControl` state between the two, for instance I want to be able to grant and check roles from both contracts but having one source of truth, which in this case is my contract `Control` which inherits `AccessControl`.

```
contract Control is Pausable, AccessControl {
    bytes32 public constant PAUSER_ROLE = keccak256("PAUSER_ROLE");
    bytes32 public constant MINTER_ROLE = keccak256("MINTER_ROLE");
    bytes32 public constant LISTER_ROLE = keccak256("LISTER_ROLE");
    ...
```

```
contract Marketplace {
    Control internal control;
    
    function getItem(uint256 itemId) internal view returns (Item) {
        require(
            control.hasRole(control.LISTER_ROLE(), msg.sender),
            "Caller is not allowed"
        );
        return items[itemId];
    }
    ...
```

```
contract Escrow {
    Control internal control;

    function addLister(address lister) internal {
      control.grantRole(control.LISTER_ROLE(), lister),
    }
    ...
```

but this seems to not allow me to grant roles as it thinks the contract `Escrow` itself is trying to grant the role instead of the `msg.sender`.

What am I doing wrong?